# Access model object in property editor in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, custom-object, propertyeditor, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have a Map of two custom objects as property in my Model object that I display in JSP by directly binding it in path and items attribute of `<form:select>`

```
<form:select id="selectedpbrtypes" multiple="true" items="${prescriber.selectedpbrtypes}" path="selectedpbrtypes"/>
```

On submission I get a comma separated string of all selected values of `<form:options>`. 
Now the issue that I want to access separate property of Model object

```
private Map<Integer, PrescriberTypeModel> availablePbrTypes
```

And use availablePbrTypes to fetch all PrescriberTypeModel based on values in comma separated string in setAsText method of property editor and create a Map. 
Please help as I have no idea how to access some other object in property editor.